# ASP MVC 2 Ninject

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject

I'm trying to learn a bit about MVC and have come across a problem when using Ninject.  I want to bind repositories but keep getting the 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' error.

I have created my NinjectControllerFactory:

```
public class NinjectControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    // A Ninject "kernel" is the thing that can supply object instances
    private IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new SportsShopServices());

    // ASP .NET MVC calls this to get the controller for each request
    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext context, Type controllerType)
    {
        if (controllerType == null)
            return null;
        return (IController) kernel.Get(controllerType);
    }

    // Configure how abstract sevice types are mapped to concrete implementations
    private class SportsShopServices : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<IProductRepository>().To<SqlProductsRepository>()
                .WithConstructorArgument("connectionString", 
                ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppDb"].ConnectionString);
        }
    }
}
```

and my controller :

```
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
    private IProductRepository productsRepository;

    // Constructor used with Ninject
    public ProductsController(IProductRepository _productsRepository)
    {
        this.productsRepository = _productsRepository;
    }

    public ViewResult List()
    {
        return View(productsRepository.Products.ToList());
    }
}
```

I have modified the Web.config file to provide the db connection string and the Global.asax file Application_Start() method to include:

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new NinjectControllerFactory());
```

I am working on an example from the PRO ASP .NET MVC 2 book but just can't get this work, been trying all day.

Comment: Did you try re-building? Also, do you have the class "SqlProductsRepository" in your solution?

Comment: Yeah tried rebuilding.  SqlProductsRepository is there, its used to build and return a table of products from the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want out-out-the-box ninject functionality, you are doing too much by creating your own controller factory.

all you need is the following in global.asax

```
public class MvcApplication : NinjectHttpApplication
{      
    protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var modules = new INinjectModule[]
        {
            new ServiceModule()
        };

        return new StandardKernel(modules);
    }

    protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        RegisterAllControllersIn(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

    }


    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");            

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );

    }

    internal class ServiceModule : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            // controllers
            this.Bind<Controllers.AccountController>().ToSelf();
            this.Bind<Controllers.HomeController>().ToSelf();

            // Repository
            Bind<Controllers.IFormsAuthentication>().To<Controllers.FormsAuthenticationService>();
            Bind<Controllers.IMembershipService>().To<Controllers.AccountMembershipService>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing.  I went from using Castle Windsor with a controller factory (i.e. the method prescribed in Sanderson's first version of that book) to exactly what you described above.  Things have been working great so far.  Not that there's anything wrong with the Castle/Factory method - I switched for an entirely different reason.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I created the controller factory as this is what he suggests in the book. I will give this a go and let you know how I get on.  Thanks.